# Clicking on "unsubscribe" on the example newsletter sends you to watch 10 hours of "epic sax guy"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Scroll at the bottom of the example newsletter and click "unsubscribe". You will be sent to youtube, like so

[Unsubscribe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHy7DGLTt8g)

also try clicking on:

- [subscriptions page on stackexchange.com.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZZ7oFKsKzY)
- [unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkfVdrtLcRs)

While awesome, have I discovered 3 easter eggs or is it unintended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much by-design!

For more information, please see [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/links-in-newsletter-preview-link-to-youtube).